# Change the colour of documentation comments

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I can change the colour of comments by

Tools=>Options=>Environment=>Fonts and Colors

Then scroll down the Display Items until I reach Comments and change the colour, say to Green with a Yellow background.  This does all the // and /* */ comments but it doesn't touch the /// documentation comments.

I managed to do this on VS2010 about 10 years ago but I can't remember what display item I used.  I've tried HTML and XAML comments but they still stay the same.  What display item should I modify to change the colour of the documentation comments?

Comment: That's an XML Doc comment, near the bottom of the list.

Comment: Misread XAML for XML.  If you wish to add this as an answer, I'll accept it.